# How to recursivley sum up a certain amount of numbers in array

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

I have a program where it ask the size of array the user wants and the insert numbers into the array stating at 1 and ending at the array number. Then it will ask the user for another number between the array number and recursively  sum up all the numbers 1 to that number.

---

***What I am trying to get***

Please enter a number: 7
The array size that you have chosen is 7

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

Please enter a number in array to sum from 1: 4

the sum of the numbers 1 to 4 is 10

---

***What I am getting***

the sum of the numbers 1 to 4 is 17

---

for some reason it is giving me 17 instead of 10 please help.

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <assert.h>

int compute(const int A[], int n)
{
    if (n< 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else 
    {
        return A[n] + compute(A, n-1);
    } 

}
int main()
{
    int number;
    cout << "Please enter a number of a size that "<< 
    "you want your array that is between 1 and 100: ";
    cin >> number;
    int A[number];//size of array
    assert(number >= 0  && "Error: Number cannot be less than 0.");
    assert(number <= 100  && "Error: Number cannot be greater than 100.");
    int input;// the numbers put into the array
    cout<< "The array size that you have chosen is "<< number<<endl;

    for(int i = 1; i < number+1; i++)
    {
        A[i] = i;
        cout <<A[i]<< endl;
    }
        int sum; 
        cout<< "Please choose a number to sum up: ";
        cin >> sum;
        cout<<"The sum of the numbers 1 to " << sum << " is " <<compute(A, sum)<<endl;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

1)`int A[number]` has indeces from `0` to `number-1`.

Since you access from `1` to `number` declare it as

`int A[number+1]`

2)Change the base condition in recursion as

`if(n==0)`

beacause in your code you also add the value at `A[0]`

Answer (score 0):

```
int number;
cin >> number;
int A[number];//size of array
```

With these lines, the valid array index is `[0, number)`, not `[0, number]`. Thus you may want to declare `A` as a `number+1`-element array. Change it into

```
int *A = new int[number+1];
```

Also, since you never assign to `A[0]`, the termination condition of `compute()` should be changed into `if (n <= 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

There is one major issue with your code. "Out of bound access"

You have defined your array as

```
int A[number];
```

When number = 3, you have array elements A[0], A[1] and A[2].

For loop written is:

```
for(int i = 1; i < number+1; i++)
{
    A[i] = i;
    cout <<A[i]<< endl;
}
```

In this loop, you have tried to access A[3] which is out of bound access.

Please correct this.
You have to understand that array index starts from 0 not 1.